# Chrome event triggering takes ages in large DOM

Tags: jquery, performance, google-chrome, dom

I have a relatively large DOM and have noticed an incredible performance degradation in chrome when triggering events on an element.  A single event e.g:

```
myElem.trigger('myevent.myscope',arguments);
```

takes 14ms!! (22.0.1229.92 m)

the same event in firefox 15.0.1 and msie 9 take less than 1ms to trigger!

The element is a jquery object and has been cached so there is no DOM lookup taking place prior to the trigger.  I am using console.time()

```
console.time('trigger');
myElem.trigger('myevent.myscope',arguments);
console.timeEnd('trigger');
```

Can someone shed a bit of light on this situation

Thanks

Gary

Comment: can you post your event listener code?

Comment: @Derek The event is triggered but there isn't always an event listener for the event.  The triggering of the event takes place inside a widget e.g. `loaded.mywidget` sometimes there is an event listener and sometimes there isn't. Could be either bound do the body or directly on the element that has the widget.

Comment: It's kind of hard to check for performance when there's no code to test... good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not not a direct answer to your question.

But in my experience with respect to custom events, I would avoid using trigger / jquery events.

Depending on the jQuery version. Trigger bubbles up the dom tree, this can take quite a long time.

> "As of jQuery 1.3, .trigger()ed events bubble up the DOM tree; an
>   event handler can stop the bubbling by returning false from the
>   handler or calling the .stopPropagation() method on the event object
>   passed into the event. " - [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

My personally solution is to use Peter Higgins [Pubsub](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js).

I created a jsperf test showing the difference in performance of jquerys '[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)' ( Blue is pubsub, red is jquery, Longer is better [operations per second]);
[image: PUBSUB vs Jquery]
http://jsperf.com/peter-higgins-pubsub-vs-tiny-pubsub

From now on I use pubsub when dealing with custom events, and jquery when it comes to click,mouse over, etc events.

Just my 2cents.

Comment: Although not technically the answer, Im marking this as an answer since it is a "solution" to the problem.  Instead of triggering events that may or may not have a listener, a pubsub approach would potentially be a lot leaner and avoid a lot of "noise" on the DOM.